# Need to implement threshold window in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a list of 6 IP's and all are given a particular threshold number (threashold1, threasshold2...threshold10). If request received from the particular IP increases the 
threshould count within timelimit then we need to perform some action (may be block the IP or something else).

[image]

- thcount1 Specifies the count to a given IP which if reached within a
  5 minute period, then IP to be checked for thcount2.
- thcount2 Specifies the count to a given IP which if reached within a
  8 minute    period, then this IP needs to be blocked.

For example :

IP1 is 10.32.9.99 and requests are coming from that IP and IP1 comes under threshold1.

My logic should check how many request are coming within 5 min period, if it exceed 30 (thcount1) then it checks for 60 (thcount2) within 8 min period. 
Overall objective is that request from any ip should not exceed thcount2 within 8 min period. thcount1 is just another level on check before thcount2.

I have to implement this in Java.

I think my logic should be when any IP request comes, timer gets started for 5 min and check for threshold whenever new request comes it increase the thcount1.

Now 2 possiblities

1) the count reaches 30 then need to stop timer and start new timer for 8 mins.

2) the count doent reach 30 then 5 mins timer keeps on repeating.

Help required :

1) Can you help with java code.

2) Also, my concern is If number of IP's gets increases then number of timers also gets increases. Not sure if this is a good design.

Comment: Hello All, Requesting you to please help.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you provided a little basic implementation of your idea.